# Apple TV: Connect to multiple Home Sharings

Tags: itunes, apple-id, appletv, home-sharing

Is it possible to connect one Apple TV to multiple iTunes Home Sharings?

I have two Macs that are connected to different Apple IDs, and I want to access both of them via the Apple TVs Computers section. The problem is that I can enter only one Apple ID for Home Sharing on the Apple TV.

How do I connect to the second iTunes library without losing the connection to the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not currently possible to set up Home Sharing with multiple Apple IDs on an Apple TV. As far as I can tell there is no way to share an iTunes library with Apple TV without setting up Home Sharing.